# Basic python - calculating %change between close and open price

Tags: python, oop, object-oriented-analysis

I've got the following question and the challenging part of for me is to calculate the wanted value without using panda.

> Question :
>
> 1. Please download a CSV file containing the stock history of some companies, for example from: 
>    http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=GOOG 
>    http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=IBM 
>    http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=MSFT
>
> (Download Data) 
> Save files giving them different names to a local folder on your drive
>
> 2. Write a program that searches for CSV files with stock rates in a given folder and for every one of them:
> 3. Calculates the percentage change between Close and Open price and adds these values as another column to this CSV file. 
>    You can replace the old file or create a new one.
>
> Change = (Close-Open)/Open
>
> 4. The output files can be stored in another folder
> 5. You can use Python to download files. An example is given here: 
>    https://raw.githubusercontent.com/prubach/Python_Winter_2022_1/master/download_file.py
> 6. Please do not use pandas, or only use it as an alternative way of implementing it along a more "manual" way using just python without any libraries.

```
from urllib import request
# Define the remote file to retrieve
url = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/IBM?period1=1639213520&period2=1670749520&interval=1d&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true'
# Define the local filename to save data
file_IBM = 'IBM.csv'
# Download remote and save locally
request.urlretrieve(url, file_IBM)

class Change:
    def __init__(self,o,c):
        self.open = o
        self.close = c
    def calc_percentage(self):
        return (self.c - self.o)/self.o

    r = Change(IMB.csv)

print(r.calc_percentage)
```

I tried to make a new column using an object-oriented format but it's not working. And how I am writing my code is I have my data file on a separate python page and I am writing the code on another page and faced some issues connecting these 2 pages

Answer (score -1):

with open('IBM.csv', 'r') as file:
reader = csv.reader(file)
for column in reader:
print(column)

Okay, so far what I did was to use this code to read the data file I have. now I should use this formula (close - open)/open
Now my question is how should I implement this formula into this code?!

Comment: You should add this info on the question, this do not look like a valid answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).